# Taylor Inequality: Plugging in any x to find n

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, approximation

Problem

> $f(x)=\cos(x)$, $a=\frac{\pi}{2}$. What is the smallest degree taylor polynomial needed so that the approximation for $\cos(\frac{4\pi}{9})$ is correct to five decimal places?

$\cos(x)=$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^n(\frac{\pi}{2})}{n!}(x-\frac{\pi}{2})^n$

If we know $|R_n(\frac{4\pi}{9})|<0.00001$ then $|R_n(x)|<0.00001$ for $\frac{4\pi}{9}\leq x\leq \frac{5\pi}{9}$

If we take the absolute value of all derivatives of cosine, the maximum value on $\frac{4\pi}{9}\leq x\leq \frac{5\pi}{9}$ is $1$

$\frac{1}{(n+1)!}|x-\frac{\pi}{2}|^{n+1}<0.00001$ for $\frac{4\pi}{9}\leq x\leq \frac{5\pi}{9}$. The textbook answer is $n=3$ and the approximation is $T_3(\frac{4\pi}{9})$. But when I plug in $1.4$ for $x$ and $3$ for $n$, the inequality $\frac{1}{(n+1)!}|x-\frac{\pi}{2}|^{n+1}<0.00001$ does not hold true. It should though because $1.4$ is on the interval $\frac{4\pi}{9}\leq x\leq \frac{5\pi}{9}$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should do $|x-\frac{\pi}{2}| \leq \frac{\pi}{18}$ and plug this into your LHS, and see that it is then $< 0.0001$ for $n=3$

Comment: @DavidK for what?

Comment: I don't think it actually helps in this case, but the formula I'm familiar with doesn't use the maximum absolute value of _all_ derivatives, it uses the absolute value of the $n+1$st derivative (maximized over the interval).

Comment: @DavidK Ah yes you are right. In regards to my method, is any part wrong other than that?

Comment: @DavidK I still don't get why the inequality doesn't hold true with the values I tried.

Comment: Actually I think using the correct derivative at the correct point _does_ help after all. The fourth derivative is just cosine again, and it must be evaluated somewhere in the interval $(\frac49\pi,\frac59\pi).$ The maximum absolute value of cosine on that interval is about $0.174.$ Use that instead of $1$ and I think you will find that $R_n(x)<0.00001.$

Comment: @DavidK AH shoot! I forgot that $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2})=1$ and not $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})=1$. Thank you!

Comment: Well, I too forgot $\cos(\pi/2)\neq 1$ for a while! I'm not sure exactly why, but doing a Taylor series on sine or cosine with $a$ a multiple of $\pi/2$ is confusing to me. I had to think of $\cos(x-\frac\pi2)$ as $\sin(x)$ in order to clear things up.